# How to see photos taken from iPhone 6+ in photo stream on my mac w/10.10.2

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

I have photo stream turned on, on my iPhone 6+, iPad 2 and my Mac with 10.10.2

I just took some photos with my iPhone, to share via an email.  I sat down at my Mac to type the email and attach the pictures within mac mail.  But they are not showing up in the photo stream when I click on 'Photos' under media.  I see things from yesterday, but none I've taken so far today show up.  Is there a way to 'refresh' photostram for iPhoto on my mac?

Michelle

Comment: In OSX Yosemite the process is named iCloud-photo's

Comment: I am not sure the protocol to respond to marked as duplicate.  I did search and the ones I found were about getting photos into iPhoto or deleting photos in photo stream (PS), etc.  I have noticed that when I take pictures with my iPhone, and all three of my apple items (iPhone, iPad, mac) have PS on in iCloud, they still do not show up in the photo stream link inside iPhoto when I go to use them for an email or a message.  I did not see a question or answer that addressed either a lag time or a setting or action to take so they would appear in photo stream in iPhoto on my Mac right away.  Tkx

Comment: There were 5 of us thinking it is a Duplicate. But your choice is "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." If they do not show up in reasonable amount of time (varies) but it is not 24 hours, the only action you can take is to RESET. The problem might be your Internet Speed, there is no way to speed up the lag time of the Apple server. If you need them instantly do not use Photo stream.

Answer (score 0):

Photostream refreshes automatically. Given the camera quality of your phone the files are expected to have a certain size and need time to be uploaded. Also afaik the iPhone only uploads them when it's connected to a WiFi.
The easiest way to check if they have arrived in the cloud is checking on iCloud.com